# Finding partial matches between two different dataframes' columns, and assigning values when matches are found

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, string-matching

I want to fill `df1` dataframe's "Category" column with the correct values from `df2` dataframe's "Category" column.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Receiver": ["Insurance company", "Shop", "Pizza place", "Library", "Gas station 24/7", "Something else", "Whatever receiver"], "Category": ["","","","","","",""]}) 
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Category": ["Insurances", "Groceries", "Groceries", "Fastfood", "Fastfood", "Car"], "Searchterm": ["Insurance", "Shop", "Market", "Pizza", "Burger", "Gas"]})
```

Output:

```
df1
Receiver                Category
0   Insurance company   
1   Shop    
2   Pizza place 
3   Library 
4   Gas station 24/7    
5   Something else  
6   Whatever receiver   

df2
    Category    Searchterm
0   Insurances  Insur
1   Groceries   Shop
2   Groceries   Market
3   Fastfood    Pizza
4   Fastfood    Burger
5   Car         Gas
```

I want to compare `df1["Receiver"]` to `df2["Searchterm"]` row by row, and **where the latter even partially matches the former**, assign that row's `df2["Category"]` to `df1["Category"]`.

For example, "Pizza" in `df2["Searchterm"]` partially matches "Pizza place" in `df1["Receiver"]`, so I want to assign "Fastfood" (which is Pizza's category in `df2["Category"]`) to the "Pizza place"'s category in `df1["Category"]`.

***The desired output would be:***

```
df1
Receiver                Category
0   Insurance company   Insurances
1   Shop                Groceries
2   Pizza place         Fastfood
3   Library             
4   Gas station 24/7    Car
5   Something else      
6   Whatever receiver
```

So how can I fill `df1["Category"]`with the right categories? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Iterate categories

Under the assumption the number of categories is small relative to the number of receivers, one strategy is to iterate categories. With this solution, note the *last* match only will stick where multiple categories are found.

```
for tup in df2.itertuples(index=False):
    mask = df1['Receiver'].str.contains(tup.Searchterm, regex=False)
    df1.loc[mask, 'Category'] = tup.Category

print(df1)

#      Category           Receiver
# 0  Insurances  Insurance company
# 1   Groceries               Shop
# 2    Fastfood        Pizza place
# 3                        Library
# 4         Car   Gas station 24/7
# 5                 Something else
# 6              Whatever receiver
```

#### Performance benchmarking

As noted, this solution scales better with rows in `df1` than with categories in `df2`. To illustrate, consider performance below for differently sized input dataframes.

```
def jpp(df1, df2):
    for tup in df2.itertuples(index=False):
        df1.loc[df1['Receiver'].str.contains(tup.Searchterm, regex=False), 'Category'] = tup.Category
    return df1

def user347(df1, df2):
    df1['Category'] = df1['Receiver'].replace((df2['Searchterm'] + r'.*').values,
                                              df2['Category'].values,
                                              regex=True)
    df1.loc[df1['Receiver'].isin(df1['Category']), 'Category'] = ''
    return df1

df1 = pd.concat([df1]*10**4, ignore_index=True)
df2 = pd.concat([df2], ignore_index=True)

%timeit jpp(df1, df2)      # 145 ms per loop
%timeit user347(df1, df2)  # 364 ms per loop

df1 = pd.concat([df1], ignore_index=True)
df2 = pd.concat([df2]*100, ignore_index=True)

%timeit jpp(df1, df2)      # 666 ms per loop
%timeit user347(df1, df2)  # 88 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I've spent hours and hours and tried hundreds of lines of different methods with no luck but this finally did it. 

I've tried to avoid for loops with dataframes but this just seems much simpler than the pandas's own methods, and probably doesn't have any issues unless there are thousands of receivers?

Can you explain what you mean by "last match only will stick where multiple categories are found"?

Comment: @KMFR, First point, the method slows down more when you have a larger number of categories; otherwise should be fine. Second point, let's say you have a receiver called "Insurance Shop"... this will be mapped to groceries instead of insurance company.. it will map to the second match as per `df2` row order.

Comment: Ok thanks @jpp, I will avoid too vague search terms.

Comment: Maybe `Series.replace` for a vectorised solution when data is large?

Comment: @user3471881, No, because OP wants partial matches, `replace` requires exact matches.

Comment: Was just gonna ask you to show performance when categories are large - very good update and thank you for doing it so I didn't have to :D

Comment: @Vaishali, I tried to but it came up with some indexing error :(. I give you free rein to update the benchmarking if you manage it. Or add it to yours and I'll delete from my post.

Comment: Oh ok, since the df2 was updated using concat, it contained duplicate indices which wouldn't work with map. Created mapper dict and updated benchmark in may post. Didn't want to alter yours

Answer (score 4):

One more solution using str.extract

```
pat = '('+'|'.join(df2['Searchterm'])+')'
df1["Category"] = df1['Receiver'].str.extract(pat)[0].map(df2.set_index('Searchterm')['Category'].to_dict()).fillna('')

    Receiver            Category
0   Insurance company   Insurances
1   Shop                Groceries
2   Pizza place         Fastfood
3   Library 
4   Gas station 24/7    Car
5   Something else  
6   Whatever receiver
```

#### Performance Benchmarking

```
def jpp(df1, df2):
    for tup in df2.itertuples(index=False):
        df1.loc[df1['Receiver'].str.contains(tup.Searchterm, regex=False), 'Category'] = tup.Category
    return df1

def user347(df1, df2):
    df1['Category'] = df1['Receiver'].replace((df2['Searchterm'] + r'.*').values,
                                              df2['Category'].values,
                                              regex=True)
    df1.loc[df1['Receiver'].isin(df1['Category']), 'Category'] = ''
    return df1

def vai(df1, df2):
    pat = '('+'|'.join(df2['Searchterm'])+')'
    df1["Category"] = df1['Receiver'].str.extract(pat)[0].map(df2.set_index('Searchterm')['Category'].to_dict()).fillna('')

df1 = pd.concat([df1]*10**4, ignore_index=True)
df2 = pd.concat([df2], ignore_index=True)

%timeit jpp(df1, df2)    
%timeit user347(df1, df2)
%timeit vai(df1, df2)


120 ms ± 2.26 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
221 ms ± 4.74 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
78.2 ms ± 1.56 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

df1 = pd.concat([df1], ignore_index=True)
df2 = pd.concat([df2]*100, ignore_index=True)

%timeit jpp(df1, df2)
%timeit user347(df1, df2)
%timeit vai(df1, df2)

11.4 s ± 276 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
20.4 s ± 296 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
98.3 ms ± 408 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Very cool, thank you! I tried to use str.contains(), str.extract() is new to me.

Comment: Very nice :). I'm not sure the results are *exactly* comparable because `df2.set_index('Searchterm')['Category'].to_dict()` collapses to a small container. Also for `10**5` I see performance `jpp: 1.52 s per loop; user347: 3.82 s per loop; vai: 1.62 s per loop`. So evens out somewhat between our methods.

Comment: The second benchmark here is completely useless to be fair. Maybe remove it or figure out a different solution with `str.extract`?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Series.replace` with `regex` for a vectorised approach:

```
df1['Category'] = df1['Receiver'].replace(
    (df2['Searchterm'] + r'.*').values,
    df2['Category'].values,
    regex=True
)

df1.loc[df1['Receiver'].isin(df1['Category']), 'Category'] = ''

print(df1)

     Category           Receiver
0  Insurances  Insurance company
1   Groceries               Shop
2    Fastfood        Pizza place
3                        Library
4         Car   Gas station 24/7
5                 Something else
6              Whatever receiver
```

Note that this assumes that each `Searchterm` string will be found in the beginning of each `Receiver` string. If this is not true, adjust the regex accordingly.

Comment: This is indeed a good solution, especially if you have a large number of *categories*. I've added some benchmarking in my answer to illustrate.